# User data is not persisting after a refresh (React Native-firebase)

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import Splash from "./app/screen/Splash";
import { auth } from "./app/authentication/Firebase";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default function App() {
  const [isSplashVisible, setIsSplashVisible] = useState(true);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserFromStorage = async () => {
      const storedUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
      if (storedUser) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(storedUser));
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchUserFromStorage();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem("user");
        setUser(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("-------------");
      console.log(user);
      console.log("-------------");
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSplashVisible(false);
    }, 3000);

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (isSplashVisible || isLoading) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Whenever I refresh my app, even If I am logged in, I am logged out at the main screen. Also, it does not shows any error. How can I solve this problem, is there any other way to do it? I tried using useContex hook but it also did not worked.